# node red chatbot with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, chatbot, ibm-watson, node-red

Hi I created a chatbot and using node red to add this chatbot different features. I connected this chatbot to slack using webhooks. I am trying to do the same thing on wordpress, so far I  read about how to do that but i dont know how to create the chatbot box on worpress and use the service, below you can see the code on PHP for my wordpres. if some one help me with this ill be fully greatful.

```
// make a function that loads before anything on wordpress loads
add_action('init','webhook_super_star');

// in the function look for a unique server related URI
// I personally like to check against a GET variable

function webhook_super_star() {
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/webhook' ||
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/webhook/') {
        //Do some cool stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: At the moment it's not 100% clear what you are looking for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a Wordpress plugin available that helps you to integrate Watson Assistant (previously Conversation) into your wordpress site -  https://wordpress.org/plugins/conversation-watson/

Here’s an article to help you with step-by-step instructions - https://medium.com/ibm-watson/add-watson-assistant-to-your-wordpress-site-6f30d537b9e5

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, i already use that but that plug in connect directly to the watson assistant and no to the node red project if i connect directly i cant add the other features like discovery or image reconigtion thats why im trying to do it throw  weebhooks

Comment: Thanks a lot i already do the develop on IBM Watson using Functions of IBM so now i can use the plugin thanks for the reply